# Vue-router always returning to error route - on production build

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have created a app with vue cli. It dev build its working fine with all the routes it has. But when i do production build its always returning to the error route. [image]

In console it's showing this error:

```
GET http://localhost/ndvc/dist/build/build.js net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Here is the `config/index.js` file

```
   var path = require('path')
   module.exports = {
   build: {
     env: require('./prod.env'),
     index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
     assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
     assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
     assetsPublicPath: '',
     productionSourceMap: false,
     productionGzip: false,
     productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
     bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably have to configure something if you are serving from a subdirectory, instead of localhost root, maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918367/vue-js-routes-serving-from-subdirectory

Comment: @Ish Man post your codebase in github and provide the link to it for debugging

Comment: it was a conflict regarding http and https.  Solved it. Thanks anyway