# How can I Integrate Vue into a legacy PHP app and gain access to specific Vue components

Tags: php, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a server-side-rendered legacy PHP 5.6 web app that I want to modernise using VueJS

Within the project structure I have set up a new Vue project and set up Vue Router and Webpack with an entry point of main.js

**Main.js**

```
Vue.config.productionTip = false

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
import router from './router/router'

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

I am currently inserting VueJS into the legacy app by inserting this code at the bottom of a php file:

```
<div id="app">
</div>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/js/main.js"></script>
```

The url of this page is `https://www.example.com/user_portal/employee_holiday_info.php#/`
However Vue Router recognises it as `/` because it is the point of entry.

At the moment I have to insert the above code on every PHP file that I want to use VueJS on. Is there a better way of doing this?

If I insert the above code at the bottom of say, `index.php` then Vue Router would also recognise that page as `/`.  In which case both urls:
`https://www.example.com/user_portal/employee_holiday_info.php#/`
`https://www.example.com/user_portal/index.php`
would render the same Vue component, `HelloWorld`.

**Vue Router**

```
import HelloWorld from "../components/HelloWorld";
Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'hello-world',
            component: HelloWorld,
        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

How can I set this up so I can on **multiple** Vue components throughout a single php file and share data between them using Vuex.

Comment: If you do not put the same Vue app inside your router, this answer is probably what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918521/372172

Comment: If you indeed need to use the same Vue app, consider to add some [initialization data](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/best-practices.html) to your app so you router can have dynamic `base`.